# Convert StringBuilder to RDD[String]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to convert a StringBuilder object to a RDD[String] and I am having some trouble.  I am able to get the StringBuilder object into a RDD[Char], but I need it to be a RDD[String].  When it writes out to the file system as RDD[Char], it puts 1 character on per line.  This is not acceptable.  I am using Spark 1.2 with Java 7.  My code below

```
val sc = new SparkContext
val sb:StringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("#").append("\n");
    sb.append("# Version 1").append("\n");
val headerFile = sc.parallelize(sb, 1)
headerFile.saveAsTextFile(path)
sc.stop
```

Any ideas on how to convert sb into RDD[String]?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`parallelize` expects a `Seq`. When you pass in a String (or StringBuilder), it will view the String as a `Seq[Char]`.

You have to create the Seq of Strings yourself. For example if you want one String per line, simply use `sc.parallelize(Seq("#", "# Version 1"))`.

To reduce it to a single output file, use `headerFile.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile(path)`.